# Build integration test with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, integration-testing

I have an application which listens to a queue, makes some business logic steps, and publishes an event to the queue.

I want my integration test to produce a message and then check the message that was produced by my tested application.

I want that the integration test will be executed in the `verify` phase of my Maven build.

My problem is that I want an ActiveMQ client which will produce and consume messages in my integration test, for using spring framework for this client I need that the application will be running, any suggestion

Comment: You can use `SpringJunit4Runner` in a unit-test to start your entire spring context.

Comment: some clarification, i want that i will have an active mq client in my integration test module, that means that i need that my client will  be available in maven test phase, is it possible with Spring?

Comment: does it mean that if i have an active mq client using spring will it be started when i use SpringJunit4Runner ?